# Branch "master" is not allowed to deploy to github-pages due to environment protection rules

Tags: github-actions

I copied the action workflow to deploy from main branch to `gh-pages` from the official github starter workflows:

https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/static.yml

Here is the version I used:

```
# Simple workflow for deploying static content to GitHub Pages
name: Deploy static content to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: [$default-branch]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow only one concurrent deployment, skipping runs queued between the run in-progress and latest queued.
# However, do NOT cancel in-progress runs as we want to allow these production deployments to complete.
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  # Single deploy job since we're just deploying
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2
        with:
          # Upload entire repository
          path: './web/root'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2
```

The only change is to change `.` to `./web/root`. I am getting this error in the workflow:

```
Branch "master" is not allowed to deploy to github-pages due to environment protection rules.
```

I have a `gh-pages` branch and a `master` branch. What do I change to allow publishing pages in my subfolder in `master`?

Comment: If you flag the question as "needs debugging details", it would be useful to add what debugging details do you need. This is my first time using github actions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like that your environment has some protection set up. You can try the following:

1. Go to you repository **Settings**.
2. Click on **Environments**.
3. Select your environment **github-pages**.
4. Next to **Deployment branches** select **Selected branches** from the dropdown.
5. Click on **Add deployment branch rule**.
6. Enter the pattern **master**.

This should allow deployments from the **master** branch to your **github-pages** environment.

Comment: Exactly. I found out later at night but didn't get the time to self-answer.